# Get API array number by comparing ''Name''

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, api, dom

I want to compare the name of a button I press with an array to find the matching name and then select that array number.

I currently have a For loop which gets all the info from every team in the array but I only need a specific one.

```
for( var i = 0 ; i <data.api.teams.length; i++)
```

.lenght needs to be the value corresponding to the team name I selected.

So for example: I press a button with the name and value of ''Twente'', I want the a for loop to search through the names to find ''Twente'' and return the number (''6'') as a value in order to use in another loop.

Does anyone know how I can handle this request?

The screenshot shows the API data I get from the call to get all the info I need.

[image: API array]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get array index of the item you can use [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```
teamIndex = data.api.teams.findIndex(
    team => team.name == "Twente";
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making this more complicated than you need to- you don't need a manual loop, just use `Array.prototype.findIndex()`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

> The `findIndex()` method returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise, it returns `-1`, indicating that no element passed the test.

In your case, we'll pass `findIndex()` a function checking for the name match.

```javascript
data.api.teams.findIndex(team => team.name == name);
```